# in Flask AttributeError: 'SQLAlchemy' object has no attribute '_run_ddl_visitor'

Tags: database, flask, sqlalchemy, mapping

I use Flask and I try to create database imperatively, but it gives me error:
AttributeError: 'SQLAlchemy' object has no attribute '_run_ddl_visitor'

That's my code

main.py:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, make_response, request
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from Model.database.Users import db_creator

app = Flask(__name__)
app.debug = True
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = "aasdff"
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///c:/Users/*****/my_db/mysql.db'

db = SQLAlchemy(app)
@app.route('/signin', methods=['post', 'get'])
def signin():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        username = request.form.get('username')
        password = request.form.get('password')
        email = request.form.get('email')
    db_creator(db)
    return render_template('signin.html')
```

Users.py:

```
from sqlalchemy import MetaData, Table, Column, String, Integer, Date, ForeignKey, Text

metadata_obj = MetaData()

users = Table(
    "users",
    metadata_obj,
    Column("id", Integer, primary_key=True),
    Column("username", String(20), unique=True, nullable=False),
    Column("email", String(120), unique=True, nullable=False),
    Column("password", String(60), nullable=False),
    Column("role", String(20), nullable=False)
)

messages = Table(
    "messages",
    metadata_obj,
    Column("id", Integer, primary_key=True),
    Column("user_id", Integer, ForeignKey('user.id'), nullable=False),
    Column("message", Text, nullable=False),
    Column("date", Date, nullable=False)
)

def db_creator(db):
    metadata_obj.bind = db
    with app.app_context():
        metadata_obj.create_all()
    return("Made")
```

I've tried to use registry() function, tried to bind it to database (db) and to app, but nothing works.